# what is data-key in <li> tag in html

Tags: jquery, html

I have got an example like this.

`lis += '<li data-key="' + list[i].key + '">' + list[i].name + ' [' + 
  genLinks(list[i].key, list[i].name) + ']</li>';`

But I want to know about the **data-key** and how to use it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 3):

usually when you want to store some more info about that element you can use data-key attribute i.e

```
<ul><li id="1" data-sub="Mathematics">Trigonometry</li>
    <li id="2" data-sub="Literature">The Tempest</li></ul>
```

now you can fetch these values whenever you want like in jq

```
$(function){
alert($('#2').text() +"is a Classic" + $('#2').data("sub") )
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Data attribute is used to store data in your element, this can be anything you want. You can retrieve it with `javascript` by using `.dataset`:

```
<li id="example" data-example="test123"> </li>

var element = document.getElementById('example');

element.dataset.example // "test123"
```

Hope this helped you,